# Stop terminal output of MySQL command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, terminal, output

From the terminal in Mac Mountain Lion, I'm running the following command:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p -B database | gunzip < db.sql.gz
```

It executes fine and the database is created but the file contents are put into the std out so I see the contents being spat out into the terminal window as it executes.

Can anyone tell me the switch to turn off the terminal output? I've Googled this but I can't figure it out. Besides, it will be documented here for others now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the command with

```
 > /dev/null
```

and normal output is suppressed but errors are still shown

follow the command with

```
 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and everything, including errors is supressed

Answer (score 2):

You've got the commands backwards. data flows through pipes left -> right:

```
gzcat db.sql.gz | mysql -h localhost -u root -p -B database
```

As well, gunzip unzips the file, but does not output its contents. use gzcat instead to simply dump the unzipped content to stdout. The `|` pipe then "catches" that output and redirects it to mysql, which uses it as input.